# How to use Simple Injector with svc-less service implementations

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, simple-injector

I'm considering switching from Autofac to Simple Injector due to seemingly better decorator support. But I'm very fond of the way you register and host svc-less WCF services with Autofac and I can't find a way to do exactly that with Simpleinjector.

For instance, with Autofac it works like this (in Application_Start):

During container build:

```cs
builder.RegisterType<SomeService>().As<ISomeService>();
```

After the container has been constructed:

```cs
RouteTable.Routes.Add(
    new ServiceRoute("", new AutofacServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ISomeService)))
```

Please note the empty-string routePrefix in the `ServiceRoute` in order to achieve rest-style service-endpoints without an actual service-name in the url.

Is there an equivalent to this in Simple Injector?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you tried calling`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ISomeService)))`? Does that work? If not, what happens? Please describe why that doesn't work?

Comment: @Steven Thanks, that looks promising. Wasn't aware of that class in the SimpleInjector library. Will try it out as soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Well, it's pretty hard to miss if you read the [integration guide](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wcfintegration.html) :).

Comment: Thanks @Steven. Of course it worked like a charm. I would mark your comment as the answer, but I'm new to Stack Overflow and I don't see how to do that...

Comment: I added it as answer. Uou can mark my answer as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```cs
SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory.SetContainer(container);

RouteTable.Routes.Add(
    new ServiceRoute("", 
        new SimpleInjectorServiceHostFactory(),
        typeof(ISomeService)));
```